# Reputation changes showing with blue background

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

I just refreshed a page to see my +10 rep notification turned blue. On chat it still shows green, but everywhere else (MSE, regular stacks, SO) I see this blue background.

I didn't see any posts about this already, and it's recent (since ~11am EST this morning) - is it WAI? Winterbash related?

[image: +10 rep with blue background]

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that. Thanks for asking.

Comment: It's blue da ba dee da ba daa...

Comment: …and it's back green again! Looks like it was a bug that has been fixed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Tiny bug there with a variable rename. Our variable literally named `@green` was coming out blue. CSS

Comment: Hahah, classic computers :)

Comment: Looks like there are some other lingering, minor issues from that CSS tweaks. For example, on Meta Stack Overflow, “edit” links on comments are appearing in blue, even though that is not the correct link color for the MSO theme.

Comment: But it's not the *same* green as it used to be - a paler, more flaccid shade.