# Where does that border come from?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, post-notices

Since today, post notices do have a blue border:

[image: post notice with blue border]

As you can see in the images in the [post notices rollout Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339700/273397) that these used to have a gray-ish border.

[image: post notice with gray border]

Either the colors have been updated without a corresponding notification, or there is another ["green @blue"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340181/reputation-changes-showing-with-blue-background/340197#340197).

Comment: Are you asking about the post-notices now being blue? That's a recent update: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide

Comment: @divibisan I certainly know that. The border is new as if today.

Comment: Quite strange that the question got closed. It is clear in my opinion that Jonas asks about the new blue-ish border of the post notices which were grey-ish a couple of days ago.

Comment: @tom Well, the uber meta is meta meta. [meta is murder](https://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/). The people here are obviously not using the tools they are discussing about. I'm fine with this being closed ... It's another sign that the uber meta is useless, just as the company has found out already ....

Comment: @Jonas, I would agree with closing this, as it is unclear what exactly the bug is, seeing you are asking a question. Or more exactly multiple questions.

Comment: @luuklag the questions are mutually exclusive. Thus, there is just one, actually. And ... the possible bug is obvious isn't it? Or maybe it's just obvious for me cause I close tens of questions everyday ... unlike the ones voting here ...

Comment: Yes, it does look like something has (unintentionally) changed. Will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, there was a knee-jerk downvoting on this one.  +1, but still negative.

Comment: @YaakovEllis it seems to be some recent change in Stacks. It seems to be introduced by pull request 420.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This change was intentionally introduced in Stacks. Some of our colors were normalized to support better contrast at the dark and light ends of their usage. You can see how this blue `notice` [component](https://stackoverflow.design/product/components/notices#filled) looks next to its other variations.

[image]

Comment: Ah okay, that explains it :) Thanks for the clarification