# Help is in different color than the other links in comments

Tags: bug, comments, design

If you go on any meta site (except this one), in any question, and then click 'add a comment', then, you'll notice 'help' button is blue, although it should be red:

[image]

Is this bug related to [Reputation changes showing with blue background](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340181)?