# Bring back the deeper-green rep change color

Tags: feature-request, reputation, top-bar, achievements-dialog

A couple of days back, the color of the green box indicating reputation change changed to light blue. Ok, it's a winter bash thing, I get it. Or - maybe it wasn't. Anyway, now it's light green. Why? :-(  ... the deeper green was much more emotionally satisfying, with nice strong contrast.

Comment: "it's a winter bash thing, I get it. Or - maybe it wasn't." ... just for the record, it was a bug https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340181/273397 :P

Comment: The old dark green color can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5viL.png and the new color here: https://i.imgur.com/YktkfoC.png

Comment: Apparently they changed a bunch of colors recently: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340205/tag-labels-are-hard-to-read-since-the-font-color-was-changed-should-the-change?noredirect=1#comment1137087_340205

Comment: They also changed the border color of the blue box: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340282/were-does-that-border-come-from

Comment: The team has [played this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321413/new-styles-new-shade-of-green-for-accepted-answers-its-not-easy-being-gree) game [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351530/the-many-shades-of-green). Someone does not like green off to the yellow, and feels strongly that shades of green should be off to the blue.

Answer (score 9):

Darker green color was better from a usability and accessibility perspective. It had more contrast and it was easier to read thin white numbers on darker background.

I could live with a changed color only on the recent achievements box, but this is not the only place where color has changed. There are numerous other places like linked and related accepted posts, list of accepted questions and answers, etc....

I can barely read the numbers now and this is a great problem for me. Please revert the color to the old one.

---

And when we are discussing colors, some other colors (light blue were changed too, again for the worse).

Comment: But why would they even do this? Is it [this attitude](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339183/196834), but applied to website style and colors?

Comment: I don't know... maybe it is just that nobody from within the company suffers from some visual impairments where this particular change has negative impact. Otherwise they would complain.

Comment: That would be exactly what I mean - not running this by anybody except for the developers. (Also, I don't even have an impairment and I noticed the contrast issue.)

Comment: Oh, yes... I can see it now... I was half blind from focusing on new green boxes ;)

Comment: (Re *"...read thing white numbers..."*: Do you mean *"...read things like white numbers..."*? Or something else?)

Comment: @PeterMortensen thin white numbers